# Trouble Merging a Dataframe with a Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I've run into a bit of a sticky problem with pandas merge functionality. Here's a toy example of my issue:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                     index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

s = pd.Series(['E0', 'E1', 'E2', 'E3'], index = [0,1,2,3])
```

If I now want to left merge these based on column A in the dataframe and the index in the series, i.e.:

```
pd.merge(df1,s,how='left', left_on = 'A', right_index = True)
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Which I don't really understand. To make things more confusing, replacing the series with another dataframe means that everything works just fine:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'E': ['E0','E1','E2','E3'],
                    'F': ['F0', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3']},
                     index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left', left_on = 'A', right_index = True)
```

Gives:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F
0  0  B0  C0  D0  E0  F0
1  1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1
2  2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2
3  3  B3  C3  D3  E3  F3
```

I'm probably missing something very basic, but I suspect this is one of those things that would be helpful to know for the future!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to use `merge`? You can assign a series, e.g. `df1['E'] = s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.merge` expects DataFrames as its first two arguments. The second argument can not be a Series. However, you could convert `s` to a frame using its `to_frame` method:

```
In [10]: pd.merge(df1, s.to_frame(), how='left', left_on='A', right_index=True)
Out[10]: 
   A   B   C   D   0
0  0  B0  C0  D0  E0
1  1  B1  C1  D1  E1
2  2  B2  C2  D2  E2
3  3  B3  C3  D3  E3
```

Notice that the last column name is `0`. You can control the name of that column by giving the Series, `s` a name:

```
In [15]: s.name = 'Foo'
```

Then the last column name becomes `Foo`:

```
In [17]: pd.merge(df1, s.to_frame(), how='left', left_on='A', right_index=True)
Out[17]: 
   A   B   C   D Foo
0  0  B0  C0  D0  E0
1  1  B1  C1  D1  E1
2  2  B2  C2  D2  E2
3  3  B3  C3  D3  E3
```

Comment: Didn't realise merge needed 2 dataframes. Thanks so much!